# How to fix canvas size not following the configuration

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I created a canvas and specified the height using (width, height), but when it comes to the GUI, it doesn't change the size at all.

```
    atEdit=Frame(Attend,borderwidth=0)
    atEdit.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=5,sticky='news',pady=(0,10),padx=10)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(atEdit)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=5,sticky='ns')
    canvas = Canvas(atEdit,bg='black',height=20)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5,sticky='news')
    scrollbar.config(command = canvas.yview)
    left = Frame(canvas,borderwidth=0,bg='#dbdbdb',height=2)
    left.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='news')
    right=Frame(canvas,borderwidth=0,bg='white',height=2)
    right.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=4,sticky='news')
    left.bind('<Configure>',lambda event,canvas=canvas:self.onFrameConfigure(canvas))
    right.bind('<Configure>',lambda event,canvas=canvas:self.onFrameConfigure(canvas))
```

I add labels to the 'left' and 'right', which increases the size of the frames, but it shouldn't grow larger than the specified size. Is there anyway to make the canvas a fixed size, even if I add more labels to it, and be able to scroll through it using the scrollbar?

```
def onFrameConfigure(self,canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Yes, but there's a lot more to it then that. [I abstracted it into a reusable Frame once](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8), maybe you can get some hints from that.

Comment: You are putting the frames `left` and `right` inside the canvas, which is a bad idea. Are they supposed to be on the canvas? In that case use `canvas.create_window()` instead. Otherwise put them in the frame where you want them.

Comment: @figbeam Thank you so much! This fixed it for me